# Change the selected view of calendar web part using REST or JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, jsom, sharepoint-calendar, 2019, calendar-view

I have a requirement where employees from different departments will book for work from office, but only 30% employees can book for a day.

Here I am using a content editor and calendar web part on a web part page. A new column as Department is added and on the department column I have to add a filter drop-down to show the employees slot for that department. For each department I have created differ views.

Now, my query here is, I want to change the calendar view from the edit web part property > selected view > 'View Name'. Please suggest how can I change the view only using the REST query or JSOM or please suggest for any other better solutions.

Comment: Did you try using connected web parts? Not sure if calendar view supports it, need to check. But you can show all items view on page & then filter items based on department using connected web parts.

Comment: No but I need to use the Calendar view only, no the all list view here, I think I need to use a 3rd party library like "FullCalendar"

Comment: Yes, you need to use calendar view only. But showing all items in list without any filter based on department/other column.

Comment: I was able to do it using the FullCalendar.js v3,  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3 , Rest API and SharePoint List.